# Trying to return the value of questions in my array

Tags: javascript

im trying to return the value of all the questions in my array and input them in my msg variable. i know im not writing the correct code in my template literal, could i get some help please? Thank you!

```
const questions = [
    ['How old are you?'],
    ['when were you born?'],
    ['Where are you right now?']
]
for ( var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
   var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
}
let msg = `You are ${answers[0]}, you used to live in ${answers[1]} and i can see you are in ${answers[2]}`;
document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = msg;
```

Comment: You should make the answers an array. Then push the answer as you receive them.

Comment: @HanYolo, do you think you could show me how to do that? Newbee here sorry

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the answer on each loop. You need to store each answer in an array.

```js
const questions = [
    ['How old are you?'],
    ['when were you born?'],
    ['Where are you right now?']
]
var answers = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
   answers.push(prompt(questions[i]));
}
let msg = `You are ${answers[0]}, you used to live in ${answers[1]} and i can see you are in ${answers[2]}`;
document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = msg;
```

Comment: The questions are an array of array. so you might want to take the first element after the index as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const questions = [
    ['How old are you?'],
    ['when were you born?'],
    ['Where are you right now?']
]


let answers = [];
questions.forEach(question => answers.push(prompt(question[0])))
let msg = `You are ${answers[0]}, you used to live in ${answers[1]} and i can see you are in ${answers[2]}`;

document.querySelector('.display').innerHTML = msg;
```

I created an array that will be filled in the loop, eventually when the loop is done you'll be able to access it.

Comment: No it wont, the questions are a 2d array for some reason.